# CSS Grid Layout Square Cells

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to make a dashboard like view, where I use the CSS Grid-Layout as base. I want to have 16 columns distributed over the whole length of the screen (should be responsive). And afterwards the cell height should be determined by the width of the cell, so that the cells are squares. The problem is, that I want to have some cell spans to span the element over multiple cells. As example I want a element which is 2x1 cells big.

So I have the basic grid layout:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: var(--tile-unit);
    gap: var(--tile-gap);
    align-content: start;
}

.grid-item {
    background: light-gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And some classes to span the elements over multiple columns or rows:

```
.width-unit-2 {
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.height-unit-2 {
    grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

Now, I tried it with the aspect-ratio of an element. This works fine for 2x1 elements, but if I want an element which is 2x2 i can't just define the aspect ratios in the respective classes, i would have to define a separate class for this case.

Is there a way to have grid cells to be squared without this `aspect-ratio`?

**Edit:**

Basically what I want to achieve is to have a container with a grid layout. This grid layout should consist of square cells (same height as width). Afterwards i would like to have elements placed on this frame with classes to span over these cells.
Examples:
This would be the idea of the grid frame, with the square cells. (To clarify, I used a width of 9 Cells in the example, because did not wanted to draw the whole 16, but basically its the same. Its over the full 100% of the screen, just the number of columns changed from 16 to 9)

[Grid-Frame with square cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXiez.png):

[image]

**Example 1:**

Afterwards I would like to place elements with classes onto this frame:

```
<section>
  <div class="width-unit-3 height-unit-5"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-3 height-unit-2"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-3 height-unit-5"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-3 height-unit-3"></div>
</section>
```

[Dashboard with 4 different elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV2OB.png):

[image]

**Example 2:**

```
<section>
  <div class="width-unit-2 height-unit-1"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-1 height-unit-5"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-1 height-unit-1"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-2 height-unit-1"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-3 height-unit-5"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-2 height-unit-3"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-3 height-unit-4"></div>
</section>
```

[Second example to place the elements on the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qb0iB.png):

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify - in your example 2, the total number of cells width-wise is 9. Your image seems to show the elements covering the full width of the viewport but am I right that in that instance they will only cover 9/16 of the viewport width?

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry for the mix up, I was a bit lazy and only drew 9 columns. But basically the number of columns doesn't matter that much, its a grid over the full width of the viewport. I added it to the Edit itself

Comment: The number of columns does matter - how is the system to know how many columns to have in the viewport?

Comment: I would just define a variable in the CSS and get it from there. Basically yes it does matter, but in the end you could just alter it in the CSS file right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

The trouble with trying to create a responsive square grid template is having the grid cell height be equal to its width. [Flex value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex_value) and percentage lengths are relative only to the respective dimension and would not be equal.

To have a square grid template, a specific, identical [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) needs to be declared for the columns and rows.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 50px);
grid-auto-rows: 50px;
```

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 50px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  width: fit-content;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.span-column-3 {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.span-row-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.span-row-3 {
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}

.span-row-5 {
  grid-row-end: span 5;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-5"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-2"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-5"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-3"></div>
</section>
```

A *responsive* square grid template can be achieved using [viewport length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#relative_length_units_based_on_viewport) or [container query length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#container_query_length_units). This is the only way (that I know of) to successfully declare an equal height of the grid rows using the same relative length for the columns.

Caveats:

- complex [calculations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) have to be made to compensate for gutters from `margin`, `padding`, and `gap`.
- using viewport length units:

  - the grid is assumed to be the full width of the viewport
  - gutters on parent elements also have to be factored into calculations
  - a vertical scrollbar will cause overflow
- using container query length units:

  - browser support is only one year old or less (according to [Can I use 'Container query length units'?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_container_query_length_units) which is showing 87% global support)

It will be very helpful to define the column and gutter values with [CSS custom properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). This allows the values to easily be changed in only one place instead of having to find and replace each instance in the column and row calculations.

```
--columns: 9;
--gutters: 10;
--gutter-size: 1em;
```

### Using viewport length units

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(9, calc(100vw/9 - 1em*11/9));
grid-auto-rows: calc(100vw/9 - 1em*11/9);


/* Variables make it easier to adjust values */

grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), calc(100vw/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns)));
grid-auto-rows: calc(100vw/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns));
```

The complex calculation equation explained: `100vw` (100 percent of the viewport width) *divided* by the **number of columns**, *minus* the product of the **gutter length** *multiplied* by the **number of gutters** *divided* by the **number of columns**.

The number of gutters is determined by how many gutters are between the grid columns, plus the left and right gutters from padding on the grid, plus the left and right gutters from `body` margin (the default margin is 8px, which is 0.5em.) The 8 column gaps, plus the 2 padding gutters, plus the 2 half-sized margin gutters add up to 11 gutters.

```css
section {
  --columns: 9;
  --gutters: 11;
  --gutter-size: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), calc(100vw/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns)));
  grid-auto-rows: calc(100vw/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns));
  gap: var(--gutter-size);
  padding: var(--gutter-size);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.span-column-3 {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.span-row-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.span-row-3 {
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}

.span-row-5 {
  grid-row-end: span 5;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-5"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-2"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-5"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-3"></div>
</section>
```

### Using container query length units

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), calc(100cqi/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns)));
grid-auto-rows: calc(100cqi/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns));
```

`cqi` represents a percentage of the container query inline size and is the [logical property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values/Basic_concepts_of_logical_properties_and_values) for `cqw` container query width.

The complex calculation explanation is similar to the viewport length explanation above, except that `body` margin (parent element gutters) is not included.

An additional benefit of using container query length is a vertical scrollbar (when present) will automatically be compensated for when calculating the container width.

I discovered that Firefox has buggy rendering of this. The content may initially overflow but then get resized to fit after interacting with it.

```css
body {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

section {
  --columns: 9;
  --gutters: 10;
  --gutter-size: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), calc(100cqi/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns)));
  grid-auto-rows: calc(100cqi/var(--columns) - var(--gutter-size)*var(--gutters)/var(--columns));
  gap: var(--gutter-size);
  padding: var(--gutter-size);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.span-column-3 {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.span-row-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.span-row-3 {
  grid-row-end: span 3;
}

.span-row-5 {
  grid-row-end: span 5;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-5"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-2"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-5"></div>
  <div class="span-column-3 span-row-3"></div>
</section>
```

---

### Original Answer

---

Your question is very confusing and seems to be contradictory. This is what I came up with that creates squares based on the width.

- Remove `grid-auto-rows`
- Remove `align-content` (no effect)
- Add `aspect-ratio: 1` to the grid items
- Add `aspect-ratio: auto` to the span classes

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}

div {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.width-unit-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  aspect-ratio: auto;
}

.height-unit-2 {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  aspect-ratio: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="width-unit-2 height-unit-2"></div>
  <div class="height-unit-2"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-2"></div>
  <div class="height-unit-2"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="width-unit-2"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="height-unit-2"></div>
  <div class="width-unit-2 height-unit-2"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="width-unit-2"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a good start, thank you. But i would like to have something like a "frame" for those elements. It could be that there are only 4 elements with sizes [4x7, 4x2, 4x7, 4x5] and the base cell should then still be a square, but the elements should have the right sizes,. I know its a bit complicated, and if you have followup question feel free to ask 

Comment: @Smiley444 I've updated my answer to include how to create a square grid template

Answer (score 0):

The `aspect-ratio` of the square is actually `1x1`, then CSS sets its size to whether `height` or `width`

Comment: Yes, but I want to have the cells have an aspect-ratio of 1 / 1 and not the elements in the grid layout, because i want to have elements which span over 2x1 square-cells. Or is there a possibility to set the aspect ratio of the cells not just the elements?